# Chef fails to bootstrap

Tags: chef

I'm trying to create my first Chef node. I've got my laptop as the admin machine and VMs `alaska` and `kentucky` as the Chef server and node, respectively. This is strange because it's coming back as "No such file or directory" but it looks like it's trying to make an RPC call.

```
laptop :: ~/chef/test ‹master› » knife bootstrap kentucky --sudo -x parallels -N "target1"
Bootstrapping Chef on kentucky
kentucky knife sudo password:
Enter your password:
kentucky
kentucky Starting Chef Client, version 11.8.2
kentucky Creating a new client identity for target1 using the validator key.
kentucky
kentucky ================================================================================
kentucky Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "target1"
kentucky ================================================================================
kentucky
kentucky
kentucky [2014-01-30T16:17:04-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
kentucky Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
kentucky [2014-01-30T16:17:04-05:00] ERROR: No such file or directory - getaddrinfo
kentucky [2014-01-30T16:17:04-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Beginning of referenced stack trace:

```
Generated at 2014-01-30 16:17:04 -0500
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - getaddrinfo
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
<snip>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

The description "No such file or directory" sounds really weird. But I suggest to double-check your configuration of `chef_server_url` (in `.chef/knife.rb`). I assume that this points to the wrong chef server.

Can you communicate with the Chef server from your workstation? (try e.g. `knife user list`)